# How to change default module?

Tags: module, zend-framework3

I have installed ZF3 and the module by default is "Application". I would like to change this module by default by other. How can I do that?

**Edit I:**
I have made some changes but it doesn't work:

**/config/modules.config.php**

```
return [
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'Test',
];
```

**/module/Test/config/module.config.php**

```
<?php
namespace Test;

use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'home' => [
                'type'    => "Literal",
                'options' => [
                    // Change this to something specific to your module
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller'    => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => [
                    // You can place additional routes that match under the
                    // route defined above here.
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            'Test' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
];
```

And the result that I get when I try to access to http://localhost is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException:
>   Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template
>   "error"; resolver could not resolve to a file in
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\shop\vendor\zendframework\zend-view\src\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php:494
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\shop\vendor\zendframework\zend-view\src\View.php(207):
>   Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render() #1
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\shop\vendor\zendframework\zend-view\src\View.php(236):
>   Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel)) #2
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\shop\vendor\zendframework\zend-view\src\View.php(200):
>   Zend\View\View->renderChildren(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel)) #3
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\shop\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(105):
>   Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel)) #4
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\shop\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(322):
>   Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy->render(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>   5 C:\Apache24\htdocs\shop\ve in C:\Apache24\htdocs\shop\vendor\zendframework\zend-view\src\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php
>   on line 494

**Edit II (fixed):**

**/config/modules.config.php**

```
return [
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'Test',
];
```

**/module/Test/config/module.config.php**

```
<?php
namespace Test;

use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'home' => [
                'type'    => "Literal",
                'options' => [
                    // Change this to something specific to your module
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller'    => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => [
                    // You can place additional routes that match under the
                    // route defined above here.
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'view_manager' => [
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => [
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'test/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/test/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ],        
        'template_path_stack' => [
            'Test' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
];
```

And finally, I have added "error" and "layout" directory to my module "Test".

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must do the following:

- In `/config/modules.config.php`, replace `Application` with the name of your module. Do not forget to keep `Zend\Router` in the list of modules to be loaded, before your modules.
- In your module, write a `config/module.config.php` file like `/module/Application/config/module.config.php` and replacing `application` by the name of your module (especially in the `template_map` array).
- In `/composer.json`, section `autoload` and `autoload-dev`, replace the references to "application" with the name of your module. Then run `composer update` to update `composer/autoload_...` files.
- Add a `view/error` directory to the folder of your module with the`index.phtml` and `404.phtml` files.
- Add a `view\layout\layout.phtml` file in the folder of your module.

Beware of namespace !
This should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have added more information about my problem.

Comment: I have completed my answer exhaustively. tell me if it suits you.